# How to get single value from this PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Example

```
print_r($a) 

Array ( [Status] => 100 [RefID] => 12345678 [ExtraDetail] => {"Transaction":{"CardPanHash":"0866A6EAEA5CB08B3AE61837EFE7","CardPanMask":"999999******9999"}} )
```

i need to take `CardPanMask` value

An example: I wrote this code but it didn't work

```
$cardnumber=$a[ExtraDetail]->Transaction->CardPanMask;
```

the $cardnumber must be 999999******9999
but when i `echo $cardnumber;` but its empty return noting

Answer (score 3):

Your `ExtraDetail` key is actually a JSON object, which you can't parse with PHP easily without decoding it.

Your `$cardnumber` variable should be declared as:

```
$cardnumber = json_decode($a['ExtraDetail'])->Transaction->CardPanMask;
```

Or:

```
$cardnumber = json_decode($a['ExtraDetail'], true)['Transaction']['CardPanMask'];
```

If you plan on needing multiple values from the `$a['ExtraDetail']` key, you may consider decoding the entire value into it's own value first.

```
//you can use `true` as the second parameter of `json_decode()` if you want it to decode as an array instead of an object.
$transaction = json_decode($a['ExtraDetail'])->Transaction;
$cardnumber = $transaction->CardPanMask;
```

Comment: @m.zrn No problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$a = [
    'Status' => 100,
    'RefID' => 12345678,
    'ExtraDetail' => json_decode ('{"Transaction":{"CardPanHash":"0866A6EAEA5CB08B3AE61837EFE7","CardPanMask":"999999******9999"}}')
];

print_r($a['ExtraDetail']->Transaction->CardPanMask);
```